# blockUI jquery plugin - image not loading in Firefox

Tags: jquery, blockui, jquery-blockui

I am using bockUI plugin to display wait message while the processing is going on. The html for my message is :

```
<font style="font-size:15px; color: #333333"> <img src="images/busy.gif" />  Please wait...</font>
```

The image appears without any issues in IE but Firefox is not displaying the image. Just an image place holder.

Has anybody come across this issue before and knows about the fix.

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: What issue? http://jsbin.com/emajor/edit#javascript,html,live

Comment: Check the Url of your image is correct. It could be firefox isn't working its way up to the image folder correctly. Try navigating to your image in firefox. e.g. http://localhost:80/MySite/images/myimage.gif

Answer (score 0):

You can preload the image before the blockUI code.

```
img1 = new Image();
img1.src = "images/busy.gif";
```

..........other scripts........

```
<font style="font-size:15px; color: #333333"> <img src="images/busy.gif" />  Please wait...</font>
```

This made my gif to show up, But the animation wasn't consistent.